# For ndb.JsonProperty, values leak from one instance to another

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

So, I've narrowed my nasty problem down to this ...

```
class TestModel(ndb.Model):
    json1 = ndb.JsonProperty(default={})

entity1 = TestModel()
entity1.json1['val1'] = 'added via entity1'

entity2 = TestModel()
entity2.json1['val2'] = 'added via entity2'
logging.warn('entity2.json1 = {}'.format(entity2.json1))
```

In the log, I see this:

```
... entity2.json1 = {'val2': 'added via entity2', 'val1': 'added via entity1'}
```

Surprisingly, and EXTREMELY dangerously, I see that a value set in the first instance, `entity1`, has leaked into the second instance, `entity2`.

Is it unreasonable of me to expect the second instantiation of `TestModel` to provide me with a "clean" instance, especially since I have `default={}` for the `JsonProperty`?  Should I be doing something that I'm not.  Or might this be a bug with ndb?

UPDATE: My best workaround so far: always do `TestModel(json1={})`. But I guess I'm worrying that if one of our developers forgets to do this, we could get one customer's data leaking into another.

UPDATE: Seems to have bugs already reported to Google.  [35898756](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898756) shows that this (mis)behaviour can happen between requests.  It was opened 3 years ago; still awaiting a fix.

Comment: It's sneaky one - I only noticed while writing some tests that happened to instantiate and object with a similar property multiple times.  It isn't a bug, it's the same as any other function def with a mutable default. The dict seems to reset itself between requests, not sure if that's ndb or some aspect of how descriptors are created.  I think the only remedy is vigilance, or perhaps a custom linter rule.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb, good to hear I'm not the only one.  I'm a long time GAE user and never hit this till recently.  In the past I must have always been setting the same values in my JsonProperty's.  I didn't realize I was replacing values, not adding them.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I thought more about your comment that it's similar to default values for args in function `def`s.  That's probably the way it is but doesn't have to be.  Ideally, when creating a new instance, ndb should assign `copy.deepcopy(default)`.

Comment: That would be convenient, but I still would be inclined to consider it not a bug in the general case.  On the other hand, I created a model in the remote shell with a JsonProperty and saved with different keys in two different namespaces; the entity from the second namespace contained the key from the model saved in the first namespace.  I think there's a stronger (though not 100%) argument that this is a bug, because data leaking across namespaces breaks the multitenancy contract.  But if Google won't fix it I guess you'll have to subclass JsonProperty and implement the deepcopy yourself :-)

Comment: basically wherever you use default parameters and mutable data structures like Dicts or Lists (e.g. `default={}`) you are in trouble. Not only with ndb. See https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in this problem, I've settled on a workaround that'll let me sleep better at night.  It won't fit into a comment above, so I'm answering my own question (hope it's okay) ...

This does seem to be a bug (see [35898756](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898756)) that's 3 years old so likely not going to get fixed soon.  The workarounds above include doing `TestModel(json1={})` *always* or sub-classing `JsonProperty` and using my custom class *always*, never ndb's class (and I would have to repeat for all other similar properties like `PickleProperty`).  These work, but worry me because EVERY developer on the project has to do the right thing EVERYWHERE in the code base ALL THE TIME. Ha!

So, here's a workaround that means "doing the right thing" is localized to just my Models (much less code to worry about).

```
class TestModel(ndb.Model):
    json1 = ndb.JsonProperty(default={})

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('json1', {})     # <---- ADDED THIS!
        super(TestModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

In the constructor of my model, if it isn't already there, add a key word arg to set property to {}.  This seems to prevent values leaking from one instance into another.